# Fatal error (null when unwrapped) at runtime

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth

I was converting an objective-c code to swift, it compiled perfectly but gave me errors at runtime. It said:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Why is that ? The code ran perfectly in objective-c format.

swift version:

```
 @IBAction func conn(sender: UIButton) {
         if self.ble.CM.state != CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn{

         }
         if self.ble.peripherals.count == 0 {
             self.ble.findBLEPeripherals(2)
        }
         else {
             if !(self.ble.activePeripheral != nil) {
                 self.ble.connectPeripheral(self.ble.peripherals.objectAtIndex(0) as! CBPeripheral)
             }
         }

         btnScan.enabled = false


         indConnecting.startAnimating()
     }
```

This line is throwing an error at runtime:

```
if self.ble.peripherals.count == 0
```

objective-c version:

```
- (void) tryToConnectToBLEShield {
    //Check core bluetooth state
    if (self.ble.CM.state != CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn)


    //Check if any periphrals
    if (self.ble.peripherals.count == 0)
        [self.ble findBLEPeripherals:2.0];
    else
        if (! self.ble.activePeripheral)
            [self.ble connectPeripheral:[self.ble.peripherals objectAtIndex:0]];


}
```

What is actually happening?

Comment: One of those is an implicitly unwrapped optional (either `ble` or `peripherals`).  In Objective-C, it's not a problem to send messages to `nil`.  In Swift, it is.

Comment: How do I fix it? `peripherals` is the one for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with the library, but based on your comment stating that `peripherals` is "for sure" the implicitly unwrapped optional, you'll want something like this:

```
if (self.ble.peripherals?.count ?? 0) == 0 {
    self.ble.findPeripherals(2)
}
```

We can still use the optional binding & unwrapping tricks even with implicitly unwrapped optionals.

So, first we use the optional unwrap to get the count:

```
self.ble.peripherals?.count
```

This will either return the `count` of `peripherals` if `peripherals` is non-`nil`, or it will return `nil` safely.

Next, we tack on the Nil Coalescing Operator:

```
self.ble.peripherals?.count ?? 0
```

So, whenever the left half returns `nil`, we'll instead use `0`.

And now we compare that with `0` as you were trying to do:

```
(self.ble?.peripherals?.count ?? 0) == 0
```

Which will return `true` when `count` is `0` or `peripherals` is `nil`.  And ultimately this is the exact behavior of the Objective-C code, as method calls to Objective-C return `NULL`/`NO`/`0` (which all return `YES` when `==`-compared with `0`).

Comment: Nope, this didn't help. I'm still getting the same error. If this helps, this is the link to the library: [link](https://github.com/RedBearLab/iOS/tree/master/BLEFramework/BLE) BLE.h and BLE.swift have `peripherals` in them.

Comment: Is `ble` nil possibly?  Set some breakpoints.  Do some debugging.  Find out what's `nil` and shouldn't be.

Comment: I did that's why I stated `peripherals` for sure.

Comment: Infact i got this error : _/Users/RakshithGB/Desktop/blutest/blutest/ViewController.swift:60:21: Operand of postfix '?' should have optional type; type is 'BLE'_
when I tried to add `?` after ble as you suggested.

Comment: Try adding it after `peripherals`

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. IT WORKED. Can you now explain what exactly did that do?

Comment: Everything in my answer was right (and it explains it).  I just misplaced the `?`.  The `??` in Swift is basically identically equivalent to the `?:` in Objective-C.

Comment: Okay thanks again. I will try to understand your answer.